# How to exclude part of an output in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

i am writing a script that accepts the device ID as an argument to check the used percentage of a disk. Here is my code.

```
$device_id = $args[0]

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk |
Select-Object -Property DeviceID,
@{label='UsedPercentage'; expression={[Math]::Round((($_.Size - $_.FreeSpace)/$_.Size) * 100, 2)}} | 
findstr $device_id
```

Here is my output. i am passing an argument to see usage of the device by device ID.

```
PS D:\Development\Powershell> .\disk-usage.ps1 D:

D:                57.69
```

What i want to do is to just output that number. How do i do this?

Comment: Just leave out "DeviceID, " from the Select-Object?  And I would have used "Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.DeviceID -eq $device_id }" instead of generating custom properties for all disks and then using findstr to just get the one.

Comment: Oh, hang on, if you leave that DeviceID out, you won't get anything with findstr.  So go the other way I mentioned; put a Where-Object in before the Select-Object to filter just the one DeviceID you want, and then you can remove the DeviceID from Select-Object -Property, and leave off the findstr.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `findstr` to filter the output. Instead, use the parameter argument to filter your WMI query:

```
$device_id = $args[0]

# use argument to filter WMI query
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID = '$device_id'" |ForEach-Object {
  # output the free space calculation, nothing else
  [Math]::Round((($_.Size - $_.FreeSpace)/$_.Size) * 100, 2)
}
```

Comment: I had thought about this but didn't quite know how to implement. Thank you. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the 'used percentage' as a property to the WMI object you get back from your query:

```
$deviceID = args[0]

$diskUsage = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT FreeSpace, Size FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DeviceID = '$deviceID'" |
    Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name 'UsedPercentage' -Value {[Math]::Round((($this.Size - $this.FreeSpace)/$this.Size) * 100, 2)} -PassThru
```

Now, `$diskUsage` is a WMI object with `Size`, `FreeSpace` and `UsedPercentage` properties (as well as some WMI metadata properties you can ignore).  You can output the value of any of them by refering to the one you want:

```
$diskUsage.UsedPercentage
15.3
```

Or show them in a neat table:

```
$diskUsage | Format-Table Size, FreeSpace, UsedPercentage -AutoSize

         Size    FreeSpace UsedPercentage
         ----    --------- --------------
1013310287872 858247196672           15.3
```